# Property placeholder doesn't convert

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm injecting into my route a map where key is a property which is different every time and value which is endpoint where I want to send next my exchange, The problem is that when I'm sending placeholder to get method of map it doesn't convert.

```
from(REMOVE_FAILED_FILE_FROM_SFTP).routeId(REMOVE_FAILED_FILE_FROM_SFTP_ID)
            .to(buildSftpUri("${body.getFilePath()}", "${exchangeProperty.NetworkName}"))


private String buildSftpUri(String filePath, String network) {
    return format(
            map.get(network),
            filePath
    );
```

When I'm injecting special case and using it instead of map everything is working

```
private String buildSftpUri(String filePath, String network) {
    return format(
            sftpUri,
            filePath
    );
```

Comment: You must use an Enterprise Integration Pattern that computes a dynamic URI using an expression, such as the [ToD or Recipient List](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `to` URI is computed at Camel startup and then statically "baked" into your route. It does not change on runtime.

To use dynamic URIs in a route, you have to use the [dynamic TO (`.toD`)](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/toD-eip.html) or (as mentioned in the comments) an EIP like [Recipient List](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/recipientList-eip.html).